# How to debug android applications remotely?

Tags: java, android, debugging, remote-debugging

I've developed an application that worked fine on my two devices as well as on my client's few. Though at the moment I'm facing a problem, when my application doesn't even launch on some devices and I have no access to those devices (these are the devices of people, who downloaded it from the google play).
Is there any way to debug it somehow, or see the crash or error more thoroughly? because developer's console has a weak feature, not always the crashes are viewed there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using services like: [Crittercism](http://Crittercism.com) or [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) which offer much better features to let you catch all crashes than what Android got built-in.

Comment: I need a feature that could intercept the error and send it to me in the same form as `Eclipse` does. Full stack of the error

Answer (score 0):

Try with this application. It will catch all the logs, like android Log Cat. After that you can [CrashLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=crashLog.cutebabyTW). You can also integrate [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in your application.